# When I resize the viewport my image down to the bottom

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The site has an image in the center of the screen. When I resize the viewport, the image will be adjusted (responsive) but when it comes at some point (350-400px about) it drops to the bottom. How to solve it?

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

}
.block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;

}


.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  
}

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 500px; 
  background: white;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
     
    <div class="centered">
    
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" class="img-responsive" id="img_logo">
 <p style="color: black"> <a style="font-size:35px;"> xxxxxx</a> <br><br>text text <br> address <br>  </p>      
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to change.

First - This section of CSS is causing your image to "drop down" because it is adding an empty content "before" it, but with a height of 100% of its parent div. You need to remove this.

```
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Second - For your image to be truly responsive, you need to add its actual width, in addition to the max-width.

```
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;  /* Add this */
  height: auto;
}
```

[Working Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o1zLv0qv/)

or Run the Code Snippet below

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

}
.block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;

}


/*.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  
}*/

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 500px; 
  background: white;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%; /* Add this */
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
     
    <div class="centered">
    
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" class="img-responsive" id="img_logo">
 <p style="color: black"> <a style="font-size:35px;"> xxxxxx</a> <br><br>text text <br> address <br>  </p>      
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This section of code (.block: before), is the one that made the div stay centered in the viewport. I used the margin for her down to the middle. Something very simple, thank you!

Comment: @Zkk No problem, glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

add in style may help you

```
.block
{  
    position:relative;
     width:100%;
    height:100%;
 }
 .centered
 {
    position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%; 
   text-align:center;   
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
 }

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: In this way, the image is not responsive. It does not adjust according to the size of the viewport. The image must be responsive

Comment: My code have a text in the div "centered". When I put the text bug continues. I edited the code.

Comment: Not yet. When I resize the viewport the image decreases very, very much! IN my code example, as you can see, the image does not decrease that much ... she just DOWN FOR FABRIC BACKGROUND. Understand?

Comment: in mobile view image takes it's width and height accordingly you can't show image in fully.

Answer (score 0):

look at your codes in the part of this:

```
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

you set 100% for the height of the block.
Change it into auto, as follows:

```
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`vertical-align` would not change anything that you can remove it.